# Minimise namespace pollution when copying data with parse

Tags: rebol, rebol3

When using `parse` to extract values from data I often end up declaring globals to capture the `copy` data.
For example,

```
numbers: none
rule: [ thru 5 copy numbers to 10 to end ]
parse [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ] [ rule ]
```

What would be the best way to do this without using `numbers` as a global?
Should I define a `context` to wrapper the whole lot or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A context won't work without declaring the variables inside the context

```
>> unset 'a
>> context [ parse "aa" [ copy a to end ]]
>> a
== "aa"
```

In the same way you can use your parse rules inside a function with the variables declared as local to stop them polluting the global name space.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of R2. Yes, wrapping the whole lot in a context (using CONTEXT) is straight forward. You could also do this using USE:

```
use [numbers][
    numbers: none
    rule: [ thru 5 copy numbers to 10 to end ]
    parse [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ] [ rule ]
]
```

And as Graham says, use the local variable of a function which will set NUMBERS to none by default.

I often will use USE to convey to myself that the context is transient, or to create a private context.

Comment: In this case no need to "numbers: none", as it is necessary if you use CONTEXT.

Comment: Endo yes that's true if the rule succeeds like this example, but say my example only contained the first 4 numbers, and I didn't have "numbers: none", then numbers would have no value, i.e it would be unset!, which is the default behaviour with USE in Rebol 2. That may or may not be want you would want. USE in Rebol 3 has different behaviour and will automatically set numbers to none.

Comment: Thank you Brett, I didn't know that USE behaves different in R3.